# Has anyone tried NetBeans 6.5 Python IDE?

Tags: python, ide, netbeans

Has anyone tried the [NetBeans 6.5 Python IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans#Other_NetBeans_IDE_Bundles)?

What are your opinions? Is it better/worse than [PyDev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyDev)? Do you like it? How does it integrate with source control tools (especially [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial))?

Comment: Has NetBeans improved since this was asked? I tried the PHP version when it was in early release and it was so full of memory leaks that I bailed on it. Is that the state the Python early release is in? Or is it almost ready for human consumption?

Comment: it hasn't improved much. in the meantime the pydev extensions (autoimport and the like) have been released open thanks to aptana. For now, I stick with pydev.

Answer (score 5):

I will share some of the feelings from using it for quite a while now. Things that are roughly the same quality as in Eclipse+Pydev+mercurial:

1. editor, code-completion
2. debugger features

Things that are better:

1. autoimport
2. color schemes (Norway today rocks)
3. Mercurial support (though it is getting better and better in Eclipse)

Things that are worse:

1. zipped egg packages are not recognized for either code completion or the autoimport
2. libdyn packages (e.g. datetime) are not recognized
3. debugger is having trouble with multiprocessing package
4. you cannot choose file from outside of the project (/usr/bin/paster) to be the main file (this is what I use to debug [Pylons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pylons_%28web_framework%29) applications)

Does anyone have something to add to the list?

Comment: I had trouble with the code completion, but it must be the egg issue you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

BraveSirFoobar, it would be nice to know more about what problems you found -- the very, very slow part, as well as the crash. The first time you run the IDE it will index information about your Python platform and project and libraries - such that it can do quick code completion, go to declaration etc. later - but once that's done it's not supposed to be slow - but there might be bugs.

Mercurial should definitely be supported well, since the NetBeans project itself (and Solaris and Java) are all hosted in Mercurial repositories.

We plan to have really deep support for Python, much in the style of our Ruby support. One of the things which really helped in our Ruby work was the feedback from our early adopters, so if you try Python and have issues with it, please let us know so we can fix it.   (Feedback links here: http://wiki.netbeans.org/Python )

-- Tor

Answer (score 2):

Compared to pydev, I found it very, very slow, and it crashed (once) when I created a project from existing sources. It's still beta, though.

Integration with SCMs will be as good as netbeans is already (I only tried subversion, which worked fine).

Feature-wise it was about the same : refactor, debugging, code assist... I'll stick with pydev for the moment, which is IMHO a great tool.

Answer (score 2):

Sun use Mercurial internally now, so expect that their IDE support for it will be top notch.

Answer (score 2):

Having worked with PyDev and PyDev extension for Eclipse for the past few months, the move to NetBeans has been a very pleasurable one.

Without having to hunt all the different plug-ins for PyDev and Eclipse, NetBeans had everything I needed out of the box:
auto completion, super fast index search, style control import control, you name it.
And it seemed LESS bug prone than Eclipse (which is pretty stable).
Also, the built-in Vim like auto code snippets it uses are just fantastic.
IMO, it beats Eclipse hands down.

I'm hooked.

Answer (score 1):

I started using it a little while back and I like it.  I usually develop in a simple editor (SciTE), NetBeans is nice to organize larger projects.

[wrote about it briefly here](http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com/2008/12/python-trying-out-netbeans-ide.html)

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this, I decided to go ahead with PyDev than NetBeans.

However best wishes to NetBeans team for a faster and better Python support. Cant wait for that :)

Answer (score 0):

How does it compare with PyDev Extensions? I've recently installed it and, to be honest, couldn't imagine myself going back to PyDev.

NetBeans seems interesting though, if only I wasn't already hooked onto a couple of other Eclipse plug-ins as well.