# Code completion in NetBeans' python plugin does not work properly

Tags: python, netbeans, netbeans6.8

I am asking on StackOverflow because surely I am doing something completely silly and I hope S.O. might provide me with a quick answer. I've installed the latest stable Python-plugin for NetBeans.  It works great, and I tested code completion with various packages such as `sys`, `os` and so on. It works beautifully.

However, it does not seem to pick up the code completion for the code in my own project.

I created a package called `mypackage` (it has __init__.py as well), and in it I have a module called mymodule.py. Inside `mymodule` I've put a class called `MyClass`, complete with doc-strings and all.

Please refer to this screenshot to describe what happens in code-completion:
[alt text http://rasterburn.org/~sgt/stuff2/pythonproblem.png](http://rasterburn.org/~sgt/stuff2/pythonproblem.png)

As you see, it's suggesting irrelevant things, as opposed to just `MyClass`.
*(Note that if I execute mymodule.MyClass() it works 100%, it's just that I would really like code completion on my own code)*

Hope I'm just doing something silly here...  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid to tell you that this is a [Known Bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=153261) for over a year. [Some people have suggested](http://forums.netbeans.org/post-68785.html&highlight=) that it seems the Python development in NetBeans is stalled.

Personally, I'm using [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/). [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) is still under active support, and the [auto-completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698/is-there-an-ide-that-provides-code-completion-for-python/715#715) is smart. In addition, it supports more variety in [syntax-highlighting](http://xavierho.com/temp/syntax-highlighting-compare.png). (This is my personal configuration.)

I would recommend you switch to another IDE while you can. If you're using Jython, let me know how that works out for you. Share with us your solution when you have one. =]

**Related topic:**

[Has anyone tried NetBeans 6.5 Python IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371037/has-anyone-tried-netbeans-6-5-python-ide)

Comment: Thanks for the response, Xavier.  If I only had more time, I would assign that project to myself. :(